# Difference between Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft SQL Server Express interface

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I am learning C# using Murach's C# 2015 book. I am pretty much finished with the class (class ends in 3 days). The book has something like 26 chapters and I have read 23 of them, so basically the whole book. The book briefly covers some stuff about databases but I would like to dive in a little deeper. The book touches on Microsoft SQL Server Express. I've also did a little looking online and I think this is where I want to start is with Microsoft SQL Server Express. Like I said this isn't so much for a real world application, instead it is just so I can dive deeper and really learn the ins and outs of building a database. I like the idea that (as I understand): Microsoft SQL Server Express can be used without a server. I fact, I can embed it into my Microsoft Visual Studio C# project if I want to. Also, as I understand, it can also be used for a decent sized database. And lastly, don't hate me, but I like the idea of using a Microsoft project... since I am already using a Microsoft product (Visual Studio).

So... My question is this... Is there some reason I should just absolutely not use Microsoft SQL Server Express? If not... Then I have been trying to find a comprehensive guide / book / tutorial on Microsoft SQL Server Express that covers all the ins and outs of the application. But I am not having much luck... Is this because Microsoft SQL Server Express is basically identical to Microsoft SQL Server? Can I just use a Microsoft SQL Server guide / book / tutorial? Or are the interfaces quite a bit different? I don't want to be going through a guide or worse... Buy a book... and have it keep referring to features that are not relevant to Microsoft SQL Server Express. Any advise? Are the 2 virtually identical as far as the interfaces? Or is it like apples and oranges?

Comment: SQL Server express is indeed a feature-limited version of SQL Server; a good comparison is on "Read the datasheet" here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-2019-comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between SQL Server Express vs the regular version, is quite minimal for someone just trying to lean the in's and out's of the product.

I have clients that have used the Express version for many, many years - in production - without ever needing the more complete (and much more expensive) paid versions - so by all means, start with the express version - you won't need to learn anything that won't be applicable to the bigger version.

When time comes, if ever, that you want to try all of the features in the paid version, you also have the option of using th Developer version of SQL Server, which has all  of the same features of the paid version - but can only be used for development and testing purposes, and is completely free.

(Neither of these versions can be embedded - I would stay away from any embedded version of SQL Server if your goal is to learn SQL Server, it will hide many important concepts from you). If you product requires an embedded version, then so be it - but imo, not the best option for learning the product.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: Thank you... This is what I was looking for. The last question I have is this. If and/or when I ever need to try out the developer version... Is it easy to switch a project developed with express to the developer version? I assume it is since that seems like a common task.

Comment: Yes, the interface is quite the same. You can pick your database from EXPRESS and run it on the developer version.

Comment: Yes, at most you would backup the database, and restore it to the new server - they are completely compatible.

Comment: Also... I apologize... I may have used wrong terminology... I think I meant "embedding" the database... Not embedding Microsoft sql server express

Comment: Well I don't know... this is what I read... "SQL Server Express is the most basic offering available. It is a full database engine you can deploy to a server or embed into an application. Express is free and comes with many of the same features as the enterprise edition. SQL Server Express is probably most suited to supporting production applications for smaller to midsize businesses. A typical SQL Server Express use case would be a deployment by developers who do not want to create applications with a database hosted on a server."

Comment: Based on this... I thought I didn't need a server... and that it could be embedded... I may not understand enough about it all at this point to really comprehend what they mean. Which is exactly why I want to dive in deeper. I am sure the installation instructions will cover how to go about setting it up on my computer. Thank you all for your  help!!

Comment: You don't necessarily need a dedicated server, in a dev environment you can run both your IDE (Visual studio for example), and the full blown SQL server on the same machine if it is powerful enough (and most machines are these days).

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft SQL Server Express can be used without a server. I fact, I can embed it into my Microsoft Visual Studio C# project if I want to.

That is not correct. Microsoft SQL Server Express is a server edition, you need to install one instance on your machine (or in network).

There is also SQL Server Compact Edition - this one does not need a server, has a very limited set of features and can be embedded as far as I know. It provides some parts of the interfaces of the "large" server editions so if you need to scale up it can be done without too many code changes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact

Comment: However, be aware: SQL Server Compact Edition is no longer supported nor developed by Microsoft. No more new features, not sure about bugfixes / security patches, either.....